# Chrome Extension, Add Listener Not Responding

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an alert on when chrome.tabs.audible changes condition. After reading the Google developer API information, I do not understand what I'm doing incorrectly. I'm not familiar with JS, so it is possible I'm doing something stupid...

manifest.json:

```
{
   "name": "Extension",
   "author": "Extension Author",
   "description": "Extension description",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "version": "1",
   "permissions": [
          "tabs",
        ],
   "browser_action": {
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "background": {
     "scripts": [
       "js/background.js"
     ],
     "persistent": false
   }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.audible.addListener(function(tabs) {
  alert("AUDIO");
});
```

I'm able to load the extension and load the 'popup.html' menu. If I add alert("test"); to 'backgournd.js' outside of a function, it will create the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Summary table [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). There is no Method, Event or Property "audible" inside it, so your **chrome.tabs.audible** shouldn't work. It is equal to undefined. 
You should use [onupdate](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) event. So, you code looks like:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, Tab){
    if(changeInfo.audible){
       console.log("The tab with id = " + tabId + "has changed its audible state.");
    }
})
```

Comment: Note for the future: please use code formatting, _not_ snippets, unless it's code that can actually run as an example (extension APIs obviously can't)